# How to set custom color ranges on deck.gl hexagon layer?

Tags: deck.gl

I want to assign colors to predefined ranges, eg red for 100-200, blue for <100 with no success.
I can set the colors but not custom ranges.
How can i do this or at least How deck quantize the color scaling?

Comment: please elaborate

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that

First of all, import from `d3-scale` package `scaleThreshold`, for example:

```
import { scaleThreshold } from 'd3-scale';
```

Now define your scale color function:

```
const colorScaleFunction = scaleThreshold()
  .domain([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
  .range([
    [65, 182, 196],
    [254, 178, 76],
    [253, 141, 60],
    [252, 78, 42],
    [227, 26, 28],
    [189, 0, 38],
]);
```

Then define your layer, for example a GeoJson layer.
Start with importing it:

```
import { GeoJsonLayer } from '@deck.gl/layers';
```

then define layer:

```
const geoJsonLayer = new GeoJsonLayer({
      id: 'geojson-layer-example',
      data: dataExample, /* just use some data */
      getFillColor: (d) => colorScaleFunction(d.properties.someValue),
      pickable: true,
});
```

Now you can render it:

```
return (
    <DeckGL
      layers={geoJsonLayer}
      initialViewState={YOUR_INITIAL_VIEW_STATE}
      controller={true}
    >
      <StaticMap
        reuseMaps
        mapStyle={YOUR_MAP_STYLE}
        preventStyleDiffing={true}
        mapboxApiAccessToken={YOUR_MAPBOX_TOKEN}
      />
    </DeckGL>
);
```

Thats all, I think.

Comment: Thank you! had no idea how to do this. Is it somewhere in their documentation?

Comment: @csmontt probabily in some examples on github, I am not sure.